# Wrap text of downloaded files and display them in a list

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, bootstrap-4

Good afternoon. I have two questions. I use Bootstrap Material components.

1. There is a form for downloading multiple files, but there was a problem: when loading multiple files, the text of the files goes beyond the field, how to fix it? If this is not possible, then how to remove their display and do as indicated in question 2.
2. How to display these files as a list below the field?

My Form:

```
<form action="/projects/project/${project.projectId}/stage/${stage.stageId}/team/${team.teamId}/answer/${answer.answerId}/create?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}"
                              method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                            <!-- CSRF Token -->
                            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}"/>

                            <!-- Captain Answer -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="answerText">You answer</label>
                                <textarea id="answerText" name="answerText"
                                          class="md-textarea form-control ${(answerTextError??)?string('is-invalid', '')}"
                                          rows="5">${answer.answerText!''}</textarea>
                                <#if answerTextError??>
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        ${answerTextError}
                                    </div>
                                </#if>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="projectTheoreticalLeadTime">Answer files</label>
                                <div class="custom-file">
                                    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="file" name="files[]"
                                           class="custom-file-input"
                                           aria-describedby="file">
                                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="file" data-browse="Choose">Choose files</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="text-center mt-4">
                                <button class="btn btn-unique btn-md" type="submit">Send</button>
                            </div>

                        </form>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: please add your working code snippet to solve the issue.

Comment: I added my form.